# Fastest Way to Get Unique Combinations of Elements from Sets Where All Unique Elements are Used in Python

Tags: python, set, python-itertools

I have a problem where I have a Python list of elements. I need all unique combinations of the elements where an element from each set is used and every unique element is used. For example suppose I have the list of sets below:

```py
my_sets = [
    ("S0", "S2"),
    ("S0", "S1", "S2"),
    ("S0", "S1"),
    ("S1",)
]
```

I want the following result:

```
[
#    ["S2", "S2", "S1", "S1"],  Invalid because S0 is not used
    ["S2", "S2", "S0", "S1"],
#    ["S2", "S1", "S1", "S1"],  Invalid because S0 is not used
    ["S2", "S1", "S0", "S1"],
    ["S2", "S0", "S1", "S1"],
    ["S2", "S0", "S0", "S1"],
    ["S0", "S2", "S1", "S1"],
    ["S0", "S2", "S0", "S1"],
#    ["S0", "S1", "S1", "S1"],  Invalid because S2 is not used
#    ["S0", "S1", "S0", "S1"],  Invalid because S2 is not used
#    ["S0", "S0", "S1", "S1"],  Invalid because S2 is not used
#    ["S0", "S0", "S0", "S1"],  Invalid because S2 is not used
]
```

`list(itertools.product(*my_sets)`, produces the full list of sets, but it doesn't enforce the uniqueness. I could enforce the uniqueness after the fact, but it should be faster to do it in the search because entire branches of the search can be eliminated by using the uniqueness constraint. For example, if one set is the only set with an element like "S3", that set's value **must** be that element. I have created a recursive function that reproduces `list(itertools.product(*my_sets)` below, and I can imagine where I might add the uniqueness constraint, but it feels like there is probably a way to do this using `itertools`.:

```py
def find_unique(sets):
    unique_sets = []
    if len(sets) > 1:
        for value in sets[0]:
             unique_sets.append([value] + unique_subset)
    else:
        return [[v] for v in sets[0]]
    return unique_sets
```

I appreciate any insight you have.

Comment: hello, does the order matter for the uniqueness ?

Comment: In your desired output, you have both `["S2", "S1", "S0", "S1"]` and `["S0", "S2", "S1", "S1"]`. Do they count as different?

Comment: @mrCopiCat: Hello and thanks for the comment. Yes, the order matters. As RodrigoRodrigues asked, those two sets count as different.